# Change translateX property on click event

Tags: javascript

I have created the very common "**testimonials section**" in order to implement it on a website.

Basically, what I'm trying to do is to move horizontally an `ul` element changing its `transform: translateX` property 20% each time a button is clicked, creating a testimonials carousel.

My main issue is that I cannot find the best way to move to the first `li` element after clicking on the last comment and vice-versa.

This `ul` element contains five `li` elements.

Here is a [**JSFIDDLE**](https://jsfiddle.net/lalegamero/wLpskc38/4/) file where you can see what I get so far.

If someone prefers Codepen, **[click here](https://codepen.io/LalexG/pen/bmNmro/)**.

Any help or advice would be very appreciated. Thanks so much!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you wanna move to the first li element after clicking on the last comment.there's some steps you can refer to.

1. You need to stop your execution when it's running out of the space. Either in the handler function of the left button or right button.
2. When it's clicking next button on the last one, change the value of tranform to 0. When it's clicking previous button on the first one, change the value of transform to the total space of the whole things.
3. In the meantime, update the init value just equal to the value you give to your transform attribute.

here is what I changed

```
btnLeft.addEventListener("click", function() {    
      if (init < (li.length - 1) * amount) {
        init += amount;
        console.log(init);
        ul.style.transform = "translateX(-" + init + "%)";
       } else {
         ul.style.transform = "translateX(-" + 0 + "%)";
         init = 0
       }
    });

    btnRight.addEventListener("click", function() {
      if (init > 0) {
        init -= amount;
        console.log(init);
        ul.style.transform = "translateX(-" + init + "%)";
       } else {
         init = ((li.length - 1) * amount)
         ul.style.trenter code hereansform = "translateX(-" + init + "%)";
       }
    });
```

It's woking well after I changed it.

Comment: It works great! Thanks a lot for your help. Just one more quick question...I would like to add a class to the `li` element which is displayed. 

This class basically changes the opacity to the `li` element from 0 to 1.

I have tried to get it using a for loop but it's adding the class `active` to every `li` element instead of the one which is visible.

[JSFIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/lalegamero/wLpskc38/15/) updated

[CODEPEN](https://codepen.io/LalexG/pen/bmNmro/) updated

Again, thanks in advance.

Comment: I have changed the original code and now it works as expected. Maybe it is not the best way to do it but it works: [JSFIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/lalegamero/wLpskc38/21/) [CODEPEN](https://codepen.io/LalexG/full/bmNmro)

Any suggestion in order to optimize the script would be appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: [JSFIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/lalegamero/vL3f75k4/) updated. The last link no longer works, excuse me.

Comment: it's good to set an index for tracing the activated `li` element.For optimization, you can just use the `index` instead of  `initial` to calculate the transformX's value each time when you triggered the event listener of your buttons.And the condition statement after `if` will have a little difference either.

Comment: extracting your `for` loop code out of the event handler of both buttons and creating a new function  to hold it will be a better practice because those codes are the same.